# how can i adding up numbers from an array using the foreach loop

Tags: c#, arrays, numbers

i've made an array with numbers.
i want to ad up the numbers form the array and show the result in a textbox.
i've to use the foreach loop.
i've already searched on the internet but i can't find anything that helped me.

this is my code:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void btnsortar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //opdr 9
        int[] getallen = { 4,5,9,8,31,44,76,63,88,59 };
        int index = 1;
        int lengteArray = getallen.Length;
        tbsortar.Text = getallen[0].ToString();
        while (index < lengteArray)
        {
            Array.Sort(getallen);

            tbsortar.Text = tbsortar.Text + "," + getallen[index].ToString(); 
            index++;
        }
        //opdr 10
        string[] namen = { "kees", "jan", "piet", "henk" };
        Array.Sort(namen);
        int lengteArray1 = namen.Length;
        tbopdr10.Text = namen[0];
        for (int i=1; i<lengteArray1; i++)
        {
            string newLine = Environment.NewLine;
            tbopdr10.Text = tbopdr10.Text +newLine + namen[i] ;
        }
        //opdr 11
        double totaal = 0;
        foreach(int getal in getallen)
        {
            //toaal van getallen is 392
            totaal += getal;
            tbopdr11.Text = tbopdr11.Text + totaal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the final `foreach` loop do this `tbopdr11.Text = totaal;` outside of the loop.

Comment: thanks voor reply on my question.this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] Numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
int Result = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.Length; i++)
{
    Result += Numbers[i];
}
TextBox1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(Result);
```

The textbox's name is TextBox1.

Comment: thanks voor reply on my question.the answer was the  comment under my question.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use sum?

```
getallen.Sum()
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/sTn1kp

Comment: thanks voor reply on my question.the answer was the  comment under my question.